# How does log4net call the appender?

Tags: log4net

I am working on an app with the following code, which uses the standard log4net format:

```
namespace Silas.Common.Logging
{
  using DataModel;
  
  public LogAppender: BufferingAppenderSkelton
  {
    public LogAppender()
    {
      BufferSize = 0;
    }
  }

  protected override void SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
  {
    Send(events);
  }

  static void Send(IEnumerable<LoggingEvent> events)
  {
    // details omitted. This simply adds the events to a database table
  }
}
```

This is in my log4net.config file:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="LogAppender" type="Silas.Common.Logging.LogAppender>
    <threshold value="DEBUG"/>
    <bufferSize value="0"/>
</log4net>
```

I am not familiar with this code. I have searched my entire C# solution for "LogAppender", and these are the only two files where it is found.

My question is simple: when there is an event where threshold is greater than or equal to DEBUG, how does the appender code get called?

Comment: When you make a logging call, log4net looks at the registered appenders and invokes each to do the actual logging.

Comment: Thanks. So for instance, if I have a few all with an ERROR threshold or level, they all get invoked?

Comment: Well, log4net will first check if the log event reaches the threshold, and if it does then it will invoke the actual loggers.